# Using Cassandra 3.x abilities in lower versions

Tags: ssis, cassandra, version, nosql

We had some R&D for our new project, which uses **Cassandra** as db. The research shows that we *can not use Cassandra 3.x version for import/exporting data using SSIS.* So, we have to use lower versions. (what's your opinion?)

On the other hand, we need using materialized view in some cases, SASI secondary index, and other functionality and capabilities of newer versions.

Is there any alternative approach that help us using both versions together and share data between them? Is this a good solution or we should sacrifice the benefits of new versions for translating the data?

Answer (score 1):

> that we can not use Cassandra 3.x version for import/exporting data using SSIS

Why do you need SSIS for data import/export. Did you consider using **Apache Spark** for this purpose ? With Spark, you can migrate to Cassandra 3.x

Comment: DB: Cassandra; App: .NET;  Data Source: A Relational DB;  Manager the ETL Tool: .NET API;  ETL TOOL: ???

Comment: Since I will use .NET framework for creating API for manage the ETL (time, ..) I prefer to use SSIS which is compatible with Microsoft. (But, I don't know really what is the best practice in this case? It's my first experience using NOSQL. So I have no back knowledge about ETL between relational and not-relational database using .net)